# Opening a particular file and point to a function in a Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#

In my C# application which is used to test another application, I have to show the user the source code of the application. For this,

- I need to open the solution
- Open the file containing the function
- Point the cursor to the function

I know that `devenv {/run|/r} {SolutionName|ProjectName}` opens a specified solution.

I know that `devenv /Edit {FileName} /command edit.goto {LineNumber}` will open specified file and point cursor to specified number (provided that an instance of Visual Studio is not already running).

What I want to do is open a solution, open a file under that solution(`devenv /Edit {FileName} /command edit.goto {LineNumber}`will open the file as an individual file and not as part of a solution) and go to a specific function (Which user selects from a ComboBox/ListBox.

How to do this in C# code?

FYI, the other project which is the test project is a CPP project.

Comment: If not an answer, at least some suggestions??